# NULL referenced object can access functions but not variables

Tags: c++, class, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to access the functions in a class using pointers allocating memory using 'new'. But I noticed a different behavior. Once, the object was deallocated using 'delete' and NULL referenced, it is still able to access the functions, but not the variables. When I try to do it, I receive Segmentation Fault. Can someone explain? Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:

        int ba;

        A()
        {
            ba=10;
        }

        void func1()
        {
            cout<<"func1 is called\n";
        }

        void func2()
        {
            cout<<"func2 is called\n";
        }
};

int main()
{

    A *ptr=new A();
    ptr->func1();
    cout<<ptr->ba;
    delete ptr;
    ptr=NULL;

    ptr->func2();
    //cout<<ptr->ba;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Sometimes when you try to steal things, people won't notice you. It doesn't make it any less wrong.

Comment: Translating what @R.MartinhoFernandes said to c++ language: Accessing *anything* through a NULL pointer or a `delete`d pointer is Undefined Behaviour, and so not allowed. But sometimes it will appear to work. Still don't do it.